# when do i usually optimize an innodb table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table that's always used 24/7. There is always a stream of update and/or insert  of 10-20 rows per 30 to 60 seconds.

As stated on the MYSQL documentation:
"After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on an InnoDB table that has its own .ibd file because it was created with the innodb_file_per_table option enabled. The table and indexes are reorganized, and disk space can be reclaimed for use by the operating system."

I am not sure if what im doing with the table is "substantial" enough for me to optimize it regulary.

Also, what is the impact on performance with doing `optimize table` regulary?

Answer (score 3):

In almost all situations, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is a waste of time and effort.  So, in my opinion, "substantial" is really, really, big.

10-20 changes per minute -- not very busy.  Not substantial.

Comment: does a hundred thousand data count as substantial? or maybe a million?

Comment: Per minute, yes.  Per table, no.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`; these may give clues to discuss.